# How to change the behaviour of django_spanner application on entire django project? As I am using 2 databases inside my django application

Tags: python, django, amazon-rds, google-cloud-spanner

My Django application has 2 databases (spanner and AWS RDS). I am trying to integrate spanner DB with existing RDS (following the Django spanner document mentioned at the link below). It says we should include the **django_spanner** application inside the INSTALLED_APPS list. I have multiple applications inside my Django project but I want to use spanner only for one app. After following the steps that are mentioned in the below document, it says **The `django_spanner` application changes the default behavior of Django's AutoField so that it generates random values (instead of automatically incrementing sequentially). This seems to be done to avoid a common anti-pattern in Cloud Spanner usage.** I don't want this to happen for other tables where auto-generated id keys are getting randomly generated after including django_spanner, because the other tables will still be in AWS RDS(where we need automatically increasing ids). Can anyone please suggest any solution?

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-django-cloud-spanner-database

Comment: Can you have a look at the answer below? I think your question was answered there.

Answer (score 0):

The `django_spanner` application changes the default behavior of Django's [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#autofield) so that it generates random (instead of automatically incrementing sequential) values. In addition to AutoField it also changes the behaviour of [Small/BigAutoField](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-django/blob/bfb2e20e26ad63ae41bcc9a5442e9f3b3b383b31/django_spanner/__init__.py#L71). This is done to avoid creation of hot spots in Cloud Spanner.

So the workaround here could be to implement your own [AutoField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2752) in case of AWS RDS only and to design schema with Cloud Spanner I would suggest you to go through [this document](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design).